# Get the last negative element index from list

Tags: python

I'm struggling with this one, using basic codes to get the last index of the negative element (I'm not sure how to describe this but i will leave the problem down here)

```
n=[1,5,-3,7,3,-1,9] => This is supposed to be random number but i will leave this list as an example
Output : n=[-2]
```

Please help, Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please clarify what you're trying to achieve here? It's not clear. Is -2 the expected result? Why?

Comment: Do you mean getting the index of the last negative number in the List?

Comment: @sabrimahmoud yes that's what i'm trying to do

Comment: These kind of operations are usually done swiftly using numpy ```np.flatnonzero(n < 0)[-1]```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to find the index of the last negative element of a list:

```
idx = next((len(n)-j-1 for j in range(len(n)) if n[len(n)-j-1] < 0), None)
```

This approach has optimal complexity (you look at every single element of the list only once).

An alternative:

```
idx = next((j for j in reversed(range(len(n))) if n[j] < 0), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for i, element in enumerate(n):
    if element < 0:
        last_negative_index = i

from_end = last_negative_index - len(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work.

n = [1, 5, -3, 7, 3, -1, 9]

p = [-1, 5, 3, 7, 3, 1, 9]

print(max([n.index(x) for x in n if x<0]))

print(max([n.index(y) for y in p if y<0]))

**OUTPUT**

5

0

If you would like to have the output as the negative indexes of the list, you may use the expression below. However, this will give all outputs as negative indexes.

n = [1, 5, -3, 7, 3, -1, 9]

print(max([n.index(x)-len(n) for x in n if x<0]))

**OUTPUT**

-2

Answer (score 0):

You can search with starting from the last element this will give you the last index  if the negative element exists

```
index = len(L)
while(index>=0):
   index-=1
   if L[index]<0 :
      break
print(index-len(L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the list in *reverse* and find the first negative value:

```
for i, x in zip(count(-1, -1), reversed(n)):
    if x < 0:
        break
else:
    i = None  # No negative values
```

This has the benefit of only having to look at the minimum number of list elements necessary to identify the desired element.